# How to undo git flow release start with any changes commited

Tags: git, git-flow

Simply put, is there a command to revoke changes done by `git flow release start` and if there are any changes pushed to the release, what is the safest way to stop it, since we cannot have multiple release branches at a time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A release is simply a point in time branch that is created when there is some effort in the develop branch that you want to get moved into the master branch.

Assuming that you simply want to close the release branch, losing all changes that you have made, you can simply delete the branch, i.e.

```
git branch -d release/x.x.x
```

**NOTE:** You may need to do `git branch -D release/x.x.x` if so, you will be prompted that this is required.

**NOTE:** If you have pushed the release branch to your remote, then you will also need to delete it there.

If there are changes in the release branch that you want to pull back into develop, then you will need to merge those changes back, prior to deleting the branch.  i.e.

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff release/x.x.x
```

And that should be you done.